# Cookie is not staying in windows Outlook App add-ins when expires is set to session

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

> I am developing outlook add-in and my cookie is not staying because of which I could not get the cookie once I have logged in.
>   The expires parameter of my cookie is Session.

Comment: Could you explain your scenario a bit more clearly? are you using cookies for login? Will [identity token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token) be helpful?

Comment: Yes I am using cookie for login

Comment: Can you explain your scenario you are trying? Also check  [identity token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token) if it helps.

Comment: I have implemented sso signin in my add-in and I keep some value after login in cookie but once I close the add-in and reopens it, I couldn't retrieve those values from cookie. The expiry of my cookie is set to "Session". This is occurring in windows desktop app only.

Comment: Is the session in windows outlook desktop app ends whenever we close the add-ins ?

Comment: Does your scenario require you to use cookies? You can use [roaming settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings) to persist values.

Comment: Till now, I have used the same but it is mentioned in the documentation that roaming settings is not good for sensitive data so I want to avoid that.

Comment: Depending on your scenario, there are [other authentication options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication). Otherwise, when you close the add-in, the session closes and your cookie will disappear. You can set a different expiration to persist the cookie, but then it's not going to be a session cookie